# Set type PATH for a Semicolon-separated list of directories CMake variable

Tags: cmake

Is it legit to write

```sh
cmake -S. -Bbuild -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH:PATH="path1;path2"
```

I mean `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` is a:

> Semicolon-separated list of directories specifying a search path for the find_library() command.

So is it ok to flag it as type `PATH` ?

src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH.html

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you don't need to specify the variable's type when running CMake from command line, since [the `TYPE` property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_cache/TYPE.html) defines which widgets a CMake GUI tool uses for that variable:

> Widget type for entry in GUIs.

But to answer your question: No, I think it's not OK to use the `PATH` type in that case, since then the GUI would present you with a file choose dialog, which allows to select only one directory.